# Microsoft graph api orgContacts addition scopes?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

At this moment I'm working with the personal contacts. But I want to expirment with the Organizational contacts but when I try to do a request to  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contacts I got this response 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "882e70df-d89c-4d9a-a028-cd3ad2e497cb",
      "date": "2016-04-13T09:14:21"
    }
  }

I suspect that I'm missing a persmission scope but the documentation isn't showing any requiered scopes(created a issue for that https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/24.) Does anyone else has expirence with the Organizational contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope that's needed at present is Directory.Read.All.  We are still working out what scope will be required when we move from beta to v1.0.